# Unable to fetch result based on date range query

Tags: java, date, datetime, hsqldb

I want to fetch the record from HSQL database and query is as below:

```
ao.find(IssuesAD.class, Query.select().where("user=? AND (START_TIME = ? OR END_TIME = ? OR (convert(START_TIME,DATE) < convert(?,DATE) AND convert(END_TIME,DATE) > convert(?,DATE)) )",user,sqlDate,sqlDate)) 
// also tried by removing 'convert'
```

when i save or retrieve then i do convert java.util.date to java.sql.date format.

Above query works fine for retrieving the records match to exact date i.e. START_TIME=? or END_TIME=? but it does not work for date range (START_TIME < ? AND END_TIME > ?) even though records are existed.

In database records are existed as like - END DATE AS '2013-05-27 00:00:00.000000000', START DATE AS '2013-05-23 00:00:00.000000000'.

And parameter value is '2013-05-24' which between above record though unable to get retrieved in result.

Also, another records - END DATE AS '2013-05-30 00:00:00.000000000', START DATE AS '2013-05-23 00:00:00.000000000'.
And parameter value is '2013-05-28' and it should retrieve but did not..

Other stuff:

```
final java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(startdatefield.getTime());

logger.info("final date sql date:" + sqlDate);  //it prints as 2013-05-28

for (IssuesAD pi : ao.find(IssuesAD.class, Query.select().where("user=? AND (START_TIME = ? OR END_TIME = ? OR     (convert(START_TIME,DATE) < convert(?,DATE) AND convert(END_TIME,DATE) > convert(?,DATE)) OR (convert(START_TIME,DATE) > convert(?,DATE) AND convert(END_TIME,DATE) < convert(?,DATE)))",user,sqlDate,sqlDate)))  
{               
      ....

}
```

In database - START_DATE and END_DATE both fields are type of "DATETIME".

Any idea what is wrong here...

Thanks

Comment: Verify your parameter. '2013-05-27 ...' is NOT GREATER than your parameter '2013-05-28' which is your condition.

Comment: @jayc. Sorry for confusion.. i just corrected original post above. I have also tried by hard-coded specific value for second record above like - '2013-05-28 00:00:00.000000000' as parameter value instead of '2013-05-28'. Though it did not work and unable to get the record follow to date range.

Comment: I suspicion that you could be comparing wrong data types, for eg: comparing a string date(though it looks like date ) with real date(standard date type) will NEVER be equal.please ensure what you are comparing!

Comment: actually, input param type is also java.sql.date and database field is also type of DATETIME. I have just updated original comment to include other surrounding stuff.

Comment: @Dhaval - see also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16282246/634824).  You probably want >= start && < end.  (Not sure if that is the root cause here or not because I'm not familar with hsqldb)