# Retrieve records between dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have the following query which will retrieve events that are between the start and end dates supplied as parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE (startDate BETWEEN CAST(@start AS DATETIME) AND CAST(@end AS DATETIME)
OR endDate BETWEEN CAST(@start AS DATETIME) AND CAST(@end AS DATETIME))
```

This works fine for retrieving events which overlap the start and end times, but will not get events which are fully encapsulated between those times.  A picture might make this clearer:

`Event A`
`|------------------------------------------------------------------|`
`Event B`
`----------------------|------------|-------------------------------`

`Where | represents a start or end date`

In my picture, using my query with the start and end times for Event B, it would NOT retrieve Event A.

How do I change the query so that it will show all overlapping and encapsulated events?

Comment: You may also want to consider using [half-open intervals](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16282246/634824)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE (startDate BETWEEN CAST(@start AS DATETIME) AND CAST(@end AS DATETIME)
OR endDate BETWEEN CAST(@start AS DATETIME) AND CAST(@end AS DATETIME))
OR (endDate >= CAST(@end AS DATETIME)) AND startDate <= CAST(@end AS DATETIME))
```

The last `OR` line will add all rows where start is smaller than your end parameter and end is larger than that. That way all lines that overlap with @end will be matched. You could also try:

```
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE 
 (startDate <= CAST(@start AS DATETIME)) AND endDate >= CAST(@start AS DATETIME))
OR (endDate >= CAST(@end AS DATETIME)) AND startDate <= CAST(@end AS DATETIME))
```

that should match everything you want. It matches every record that laps over the `start` or the `end`. Maybe you have to combine it with between if you want to also match everything that is enclosed within `start` or `end` but don't overlap any of them.

Comment: Of course! I couldn't see it for staring at it so long :)  Thanks for your help

Comment: @peacemaker You're welcome. Please have a look at the new last sentence as I just edited it into the answer and its important.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do

```
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE (startDate <= CAST(@end AS DATETIME) AND endDate >= CAST(@start AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: I don't think this covers the case where the start and end overlap the start or end of the other events.  I.e. if Event A starts at 10:00, ends at 12:00 and I search for 09:00 to 11:00.

Comment: Yes, it will cover. It covers all cases.