# JavaScript date range between date range

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to have an IF check to see if X date range is between Y date range. But it's not returning the correct true/false on the correct time:

```
var startdate = new Date('06/06/2013');
var enddate = new Date('06/25/2013');
var startD = new Date('06/08/2013');
var endD = new Date('06/18/2013');

if(startD >= startdate || endD <= enddate) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

This works, but if I change `startdate` to `06/09/2013` and `enddate` to `06/17/2013` it no longer works while it should work.

It should even work if `startdate` was `06/07/2013` and `enddate` was `06/15/2013`, but doesn't. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you trying to detect if the date ranges overlap, or if one is fully contained within another?

Comment: For a date range to be a subset of another date range, the start of the inner range must be after the start of the outer range AND the end of the inner range must be before the end of the outer range.

Do you want to check that one range contains another in its entirety, or do you want to detect if they overlap?

Comment: Both and either one really. As if enddate is within the range it needs to be included as some days will overlap. If startdate is within the range but enddate goes out it still needs to be true as a few days will still be within the range. So both really.

Comment: @jfreak53: You say both, but you're basically looking for overlap. Being fully contained within another date range is still an overlap.

Comment: Also, you do realize that hardcoding dates in mm/dd/yyyy format won't work internationally, right?

Comment: And you might also consider using half-open intervals.  Inclusive start dates (`>=`) but exclusive end dates (`<`).  Otherwise, you may get overlaps that you didn't actually want. [Read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16282246/634824).

Comment: @MattJohnson My dates are NOT hard coded, this was an example of my code. My dates are represented to the user that way, normal way for the users I have, then translated to ISO (Gregorian y-m-d) version for DB storage. Please stay on subject and the question I asked instead of your opinion of something I did.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you're trying to detect full containment, that is fairly easy. (Also, you don't need the explicit `return true/false`, because the condition is a boolean anyway. Just return it)

```
// Illustration:
//
// startdate                          enddate
// v                                        v
// #----------------------------------------#
//
//         #----------------------#
//         ^                      ^
//         startD              endD
return startD >= startdate && endD <= enddate;
```

---

An overlap test is slightly more complex. The following will return `true` if the two date ranges overlap, regardless of order.

```
// Need to account for the following special scenarios
//
// startdate     enddate
// v                v
// #----------------#
//
//         #----------------------#
//         ^                      ^
//         startD              endD
//
// or
//
//              startdate        enddate
//                 v                v
//                 #----------------#
//
//         #------------------#
//         ^                  ^
//       startD              endD
return (startD >= startdate && startD <= enddate) ||
       (startdate >= startD && startdate <= endD);
```

@Bergi's answer is probably more elegant, in that it just checks the start/end pairs of the two date ranges.

Comment: Well, if you would allow containment in overlapping the test would be much easier…

Comment: @Bergi: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "if you would allow containment" - I'm pretty sure this still returns `true` when ranges are completely contained. But I agree that it's more elegant to check for start/end pairs.

Comment: Tip: compare using `startD.getTime()` instead of just the date object as using the date object will convert to string first and compare as string, as getTime() compares integer values which is more than 10x faster (in FF, 20x in Chrome) - of course not vital unless one need to compare a lot of dates. Non-scientific test: http://jsperf.com/test-time-vs-gettime

Answer (score 26):

To check if they overlap with any days, use

```
if (endD >= startdate && startD <= enddate)
```

which is equivalent to

```
if ( !(endD < startdate || startD > enddate)) // not one after the other
```

Answer (score 16):

In your example, the new dates are both outside the range.

If you want to check if there is *any* overlap between the date ranges, use:

```
return (endD >= startdate && startD <= enddate);
```

Comment: @voithos - Seeing as this answer is the same as Bergi, but 2 minutes earlier, and I'm just starting out on reps...

Answer (score 1):

here is the logic in nodejs

```
    export const isDateOverlaped = (firstDateRange: { from: Date; to: Date }, secondDateRange: { from: Date; to: Date }) => {
  // f-from -----------f-to
  //          s-from -------------- s-to
  const overlappedEnd =
    firstDateRange.from <= secondDateRange.from && firstDateRange.to >= secondDateRange.from && firstDateRange.to <= secondDateRange.to

  // f-from ----------------------- f-to
  //          s-from --------- s-to
  const overlappedBetween = firstDateRange.from <= secondDateRange.from && firstDateRange.to >= secondDateRange.to

  //            f-from -----------f-to
  // s-from -------------- s-to
  const overlappedStart =
    firstDateRange.from >= secondDateRange.from && firstDateRange.from <= secondDateRange.to && firstDateRange.to >= secondDateRange.to

  return overlappedEnd || overlappedBetween || overlappedStart
}
```