# How to check intersection of dates in backbone collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have Backbone collection that consists of models that have the following attributes:

```
{
  startTime: Date('...'),
  endTime: Date('...')
}
```

When I add a new model I have to check that there is no dates intersections between added and exists ones.

So for example:

```
var startTime = new Date();
var endTime = new Date(new Date().setHours(1));

if (!this.collection.check({startTime: startTime, endTime })) {
   this.create({startTime: startTime, endTime });
}
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test every model in your collection to check if the future dates do not overlap with an existing interval. For example, and with a condition based on the answers in [JavaScript date range between date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304426/javascript-date-range-between-date-range),

```
var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    check: function(opts) {
       // returns true if the given interval overlaps with any model
        var start = opts.startTime,
            end = opts.endTime;

        return this.any(function(model) {
            // returns true if the given interval overlaps
            return !((model.get('startTime')>=end) || (model.get('endTime')<=start));
        });
    }
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/eaF5z/2/

Or if you prefer a more explicit version

```
var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    check: function(opts) {
        var startdate = opts.startTime,
            enddate = opts.endTime;

        return this.any(function(model) {
            var startD = model.get('startTime'),
                endD = model.get('endTime');

            return (startD >= startdate && startD <= enddate) || 
                    (startdate >= startD && startdate <= endD);
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/duu3M/

Comment: Thanks for the response. Should I check this in collection or in model's validate method? We still have access to parent to collection in model. And it seems there is mistake in your clause (use || instead &)

Comment: I would let the collection handle the check since it handles the creation, maybe with an override on the create method

Comment: The condition is correct: if model.end is before the start date or model.start is after the end date, then they don't overlap

Comment: Does your checking check order of dates too as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304426/javascript-date-range-between-date-range#17304654 or I need to add some condition?

Comment: It's equivalent to the answer given by Bergi and Bungus http://stackoverflow.com/a/17304604/1071630 and you shouldn't have to add anything

Comment: But what's about the following clause (startD >= startdate && startD <= enddate) || (startdate >= startD && startdate <= endD); It seems  more strict checking?

Comment: It tests if any of the dates (start and end) are in a given range, but you just need to check if the end date is before the range or if the start date is after the range.

Comment: No sorry for my english I need that is it :))

Comment: How shoud I refactor check method in this case?

Comment: Also there is need to add checking on empty collection because default return value of every method is true and after (! not) there are false :)

Comment: That should now be compatible with an empty collection, the ! was not a good idea.

Comment: Ok, may you help with refactoring your example to be possible consider there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304426/javascript-date-range-between-date-range#17304654 conditions?